# How do I duplicate rows in a dataframe while increasing one by one an specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, data-science

Imagine I have an specific dataframe with four columns (being of them a date) and let's say 12 rows. I would like to add for each row, around 30 replicated rows below but increasing day by day while maintaining the rest static. For example if this is my dataframe:

```
Video_ID     date  ratio_liked    accomulated_views
    45    2022-08-07  0.540457  0.826594      
    87   2021-06-14  0.979323  0.977446 
    34   2018-02-09  0.128068  0.1237669  
    25   2010-01-07  0.507959  0.378297  
    23   2020-09-03  0.731555  0.818380  
    85   2015-02-01  0.999961  0.619517  
    92   2019-04-07  0.129270  0.024533  
    51   2007-07-03  0.441010  0.741781  
    37   2009-12-01  0.682101  0.375660  
    50   2012-11-10  0.754488  0.352293
```

I would like something like this: (The hash lines implies there are rows inbetween)

```
Video_ID     date  ratio_liked    accomulated_views
    45    2022-08-07  0.540457  0.826594 
    45    2022-08-08  0.540457  0.826594
    45    2022-08-09  0.540457  0.826594
    45    2022-08-10  0.540457  0.826594
---------------------------------------------
    45    2022-09-06  0.540457  0.826594
    45    2022-09-07  0.540457  0.826594
    87   2021-06-14  0.979323  0.977446 
    87   2021-06-15  0.979323  0.977446
    87   2021-06-16  0.979323  0.977446
------------------------------------------------------
    87   2021-07-14  0.979323  0.977446
    34   2018-02-07  0.128068  0.1237669
    34   2018-02-18  0.128068  0.1237669  
    34   2018-03-07  0.128068  0.1237669
---------------------------------------------
     50   2012-11-10  0.754488  0.352293
----------------------------------------------  
    50   2012-12-10  0.754488  0.352293
```

The range between two dataframes is giving by
pandas.date_range(date, date+ DateOffset(months=1),freq='d')

The thing I think it can be approached:

1. For each row, create a fuction the reproduces it 30 times giving you a dataframe of 30 rows
2. Replace the column with the data_range
3. Create a loop or maybe a compression list that select each rows, applies the fuction before and then concat

It will end up giving you a dataframe of around 12x30(or 31) rows.

I've tried to code this but this have been unsucessful.

Answer (score 0):

you can use pandas.interpolate().ffill(). this command first generate gap dates between two records then by ffill() you forward fill missing values for this gap.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Because I don't understand